# How does one automatically attach a debugger to a process at process start on OS X?

Tags: debugging, macos, child-process

I have a process that spawns a helper process.  Sometimes I need to debug start-up failures in the second process.

On Windows, I would use `Image File Execution Options`, or `ntsd -o`.  However, I have no idea how to do this with GDB on OS X.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use *gdb --wait*.  For example, try

```
gdb --wait TextEdit
```

from the command line, and then launch TextEdit.

Comment: With LLDB it's `lldb --wait-for --attach-name TextEdit`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that you can have GDB launch in the same manner.

Instead, run your parent process from within GDB or attach to the running process before it forks the helper off.  There is a setting called `follow-fork-mode` that controls which process the debugger follows.  Take a look at [the GDB Manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb_5.html#SEC29) for a nice description.

Comment: Ah, that indeed seems like something I would need.  It seems to imply the parent process is no longer debugged after the vfork(), but I'll try it.  That would be sad, however, if it is the case.

Comment: Well, that was a quick acceptance. :-)  See my answer.  gdb --wait does what you want.

Comment: @jeff: you can always attach to the parent again with a different instance of gdb. I'm not sure if it detaches from the parent or not. It has been a while since I debugged an Apache module using this.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [launchd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) to spawn processes, then there's a `WaitForDebugger` Boolean key which goes in the job's [p-list file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list). If it's yes, then launchd waits (surprisingly!) for the debugger before `exec()`ing the job.

Comment: Also interesting.  How does one use launchd to spawn a process?  I've been using fork() and exec().

Comment: I'll let Quinn answer for me: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2083.html
Also check out the man page for launchd.plist(5)