# Debugging .NET Core in macOS

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core

We are migrating a gigantic solution to .NET Core. It builds and works in Windows and we can debug using Visual Studio without problems.

In macOS, however, we can run it, but still not build it due to some issues.

In the meantime I was trying to think of a way to debug code on Mac. Why doesn't this work?

1. Add this to one of my DLL files

   ```css
   // Start of my application
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
   // The rest of my application
   ```
2. Compile that DLL file and use it, alongside the [PDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) file, to generate my new application.
3. Navigate to that part of the code in Mac
4. Nothing happens. Unlike in Windows where that code allows me to attach a debugger.

How can I properly debug a part of my .NET Core code?

Comment: Visual Studio for Mac (NOT the same as VS Code) is awesome. For .NET projects, it's basically identical to VS 2019, including great debugger support.

Comment: I second that VS for Mac can be used to run and debug .NET Core projects on macOS.

Comment: Windows allows that function call to trigger the debugger, but macOS does not have the same. You have to manually attach a debugger in that case, or run with a debugger from VS for Mac or VSCode.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'In MacOS however, we can run it but still not build it due to some issues.'? You wont be able to run it unless its built without error. Also have you noticed the remark 'If a debugger is already attached, nothing happens.' on msdn page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.debugger.launch?view=netcore-3.1 ?

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4357 - It looks like lldb/macos/visual studio environment issue.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I mean that the build via Visual Studio does not work yet. We build in Windows and generate the App with the contents of publish, for the time being.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for the answer. Where have you seen that info? If that's the case, then that explains why I can't debug my .dll that way.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you have an opportunity to hook up a debugger when the process hits a 'first chance exception'. The default debugger is specified in the registry, and you can find more information in - *[Configuring Automatic Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/configuring-automatic-debugging)*.

I don’t think that is possible in Mac OS X. Have a look at *[How does one automatically attach a debugger to a process at process start on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384284/how-does-one-automatically-attach-a-debugger-to-a-process-at-process-start-on-os)*

Also, I tried your code on macOS:

```
using System;

namespace DebugConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Calling Debugger.Launch");
            Console.ReadKey();
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            Console.WriteLine("Continuing...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

This builds successfully, but when System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch() is hit, on macOS the process does not hit the debugger. On a Windows machine it does. In short, this code should not be the reason why your code does not build on macOS.

Update:

1. Use [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) to open your code. Visual Studio Code asks you to add file *launch.json* for the debugging configuration.
2. It will also download the .NET debugging extension which is required for obvious reasons.
3. You can launch your console application from here, but if you want to launch the process for some reason in the background and then hook up to it then you can do that as well. On the top you will see the menu next to the 'RUN' menu - this has two options. 'Dotnet core launch' will launch the process through Visual Studio Code and attach to it. 'Dotnet core attach' will attach to already running process.
4. If you select the 'attach' option, it asks you for the process to be attached. Refer to the screenshot below -

[image: Visual Studio Code Attach to Process]

Please note that you will have to put a breakpoint in the IDE. As mentioned above, the debugger does not enter debug mode based on the Debugger.Launch() function call.

Comment: There is.a very nice book dedicated to this subject - https://sites.google.com/site/raidecompchest/debugging-applications-for-microsoft-net-and-microso-89348563 - I read the old version (15 years ago when visual c++ and MFC was norm) and the concepts still apply since its all about the OS rather than high level languages.

Comment: I never said that the code doesn't build because of that code line.
Nonetheless, thanks for the confirmation that this in fact does not work in MacOS ;)

So, any solution?

Comment: @JoãoPereira : Yes. Launch the debugger before you start your target process. Like they mentioned in the link above - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384284/how-does-one-automatically-attach-a-debugger-to-a-process-at-process-start-on-os

Comment: And how can I launch a debugger with just one .dll? It's not an executable, just a .dll/.pdb. Not sure how to achieve that

Comment: If it is a console application then dotnet run should help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run If it is an app, take a look at https://swaminathanvetri.in/2016/06/23/debugging-dotnet-apps-using-vs-code-on-mac/ - vs code provides a way to attach to already running processes.

Comment: I tried and that does not work in my case because I can't compile/build the project in Mac. I'm able to attach to the running App but the breakpoints are never hit.

Comment: @JoãoPereira : Have you copied the pdb files (symbol files) along with your binaries? You need those for the debugger to be able to make some sense out of machine instruction that is executing and map it back to the 4GL language like c#.

Comment: Yeah, I added the pdbs :/

Comment: @JoãoPereira : OK. I am not sure exactly what is happening in this scenario. I will try reproducing this on my end (building on windows and running the binaries on macos) and will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Thanks mate!   
For now I think I managed to work it out via ssh. Connecting my Visual Studio in Windows via ssh to my MacOS running the app

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can!**

Install Visual Studio Code and then, instead of running "dotnet run" in the Terminal as always, you can start your API by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> (make sure you are not running in the terminal at the same time!)

Make sure you put a breakpoint in a place where you are going to use, and then hit an endpoint (for example, *[Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info)*).

I have installed the plugin "C#" from Microsoft, but I don't know if that helps...

[image]

Alternatively, you can try Visual Studio for Mac, but I found that this works in Visual Studio Code and I prefer it!